# Titles in structure not showing

Tags: add-on, structure

I'm relatively new to ExpressionEngine so please bear with me on this.

I'm trying to add title attributes to the links in my Structure navigation, like this:

`<a href="[link]" title="[something]">[page name]</a>`

But I'm not having much luck. Here is my `{exp:structure:nav}` tag:

```
{exp:structure:nav start_from="/" max_depth="1" include_ul="no" add_unique_ids="entry_id" current_class="font-bold"}
```

I tried adding in my own custom title parameter but that didn't seem to work either.

This could be a quick fix but I can't see it myself. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:** Since I couldn't see a way to add titles through the tag, I went in and edited line 717 in sql.structure.php:

```
$html .= '<li'. $classes . $ids . '><a href="' . $tree[$i]['uri'] . '" title="' . $title_output .'">' . $title_output .'</a>';
```

I'm testing it now but it seems to work.

If anyone has a better alternative please feel free to add.

Comment: Tom, can you please provide a code snippet of what the navigation is _supposed_ to look like?

Comment: like this <a href="[link]" title="[something]">[page name]</a> I'm going to go ahead and use the plugin suggested by @tidy but my ammend to the code above also works.

Comment: Ah, I see. Your question made it seem like you were trying to add _entry_ titles, not title _attributes_. I recommend removing your code hack from your question and posting it as an answer.

Comment: I'd consider it redundant to add title attributes to navigation links. If the text of a link is "About Us", you don't really need to add a title of "About Us" to clarify where the link points to. Titles are best used when the link destination is ambiguous, which it usually isn't in site navigation.

Comment: OK I'll take that into consideration, does it effect SEO in anyway?

Comment: I very much doubt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the Structure nav tag does not output any title attribute for links.

There is a free third party add-on Structure Entries http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure-entries which you could try using to generate your navigation links instead. You specify your own markup for each link, so you could specify the title attribute etc.

Alternatively, you could use javascript to add a title parameter set to the link text into your Structure nav output.

Comment: Will take a look thanks, any knowledge on just editing structure to pull in the Title tag information from the page name?

Comment: No sorry but you could try posting on the Structure support site about that http://structure.tenderapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly by what 'title' you're trying to output then you'll need to include `show_overview="yes"`.

> Overview (Parent) Link show_overview="yes", defaults to no Shows a
>   link at the top of your navigation that links to the current top level
>   page. Use with rename_overview to change the title.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I was looking to include the title in the a tag - <a href="/blog/" title="blog"> like this.